# Rebuild regular array to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that outputs information from DB from a single table as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [users_info_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 374
            [user_email] => foos@foo.com
            [address_type] => BT
            [firstname] => Foo
            [lastname] => Faa
            [vat_number] => 
            [country_code] => US
            [address] => Jajajaja
            [city] => KOKOKOKOKOKO
            [state_code] => MD
            [zipcode] => 20745
            [phone] => 2401111111
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [users_info_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 374
            [user_email] => foos@foo.com
            [address_type] => ST
            [firstname] => Foos
            [lastname] => Faas
            [vat_number] => 
            [country_code] => US
            [address] => JSUSUSUS
            [city] => LASOSLSL
            [state_code] => DC
            [zipcode] => 1234
            [phone] => 1234567895
        )
        // ... about 500 records...
)
```

What I'm looking for is to re-build each block of that array so the output would be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [users_info_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 374
            [user_email] => foos@foo.com
            [phone] => 3213213213
            [bt] => array (
                [firstname] => Foo
                [lastname] => Faa
                [vat_number] => 
                [country_code] => US
                [address] => Jajajaja
                [city] => KOKOKOKOKOKO
                [state_code] => MD
                [zipcode] => 20745
                [phone] => 2401111111
              )
            [st] => array (
                [firstname] => Foos
                [lastname] => Faas
                [vat_number] => 
                [country_code] => US
                [address] => JSUSUSUS
                [city] => LASOSLSL
                [state_code] => DC
                [zipcode] => 1234
                [phone] => 1234567895
              )
        )
```

I don't even know how to start the code to make this happen, also, if you notice, the ST and BT keys came from the key address_type which is show in the first array, ST is for "shipping address" and BT is for Billing address, some users have one shipping and one for billing, but there are user who have 3 or more address for shipping...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using more than one query? Grab each unique `users_info_id` and store them in an array. Then loop over that array and query for the unique address types and store those outputs in that same array?

Comment: So if you loop over `$users as $user` using `$user['users_info_id']` for the database query condition, you could store each row like `$user[$addressTypeFromDB] = $dbRow;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that situation, I would use such a loop:

```
$outputArray = array();

$previousUserId = -1;

// Loop through all source records.
foreach ($inputRows as $row) {

   // If the current row has a different user id thn the row before,
   // add the output row to the final output array and prepare a new output row. 
   // If the current row has the same user id as the row before, 
   // just add further address information.
   // This handles also the start situation, $previousUserId = -1.
   if ($previousUserId != $row->user_id) {
       if ($previousUserId >= 0) {
           $outputArray[] = $outputRow;
       }
       $outputRow = array();

       // Copy main attributes
       $outputRow['users_info_id'] = $row->users_info_id;
       $outputRow['user_id'] = $row->user_id;
       $outputRow['user_email'] = $row->user_email;
       $outputRow['phone'] = $row->phone;
   }

   $previousUserId = $row->user_id;

   // Create a suitable address subarray and fill it.
   if ($row->address_type == 'BT') {
       $outputRow['bt'] = array();
       $outputRow['bt']['firstname'] = $row->firstname;
       $outputRow['bt']['lastname'] = $row->lastname;
       ...
   } 
   if ($row->address_type == 'ST') {
      // dito, but for ['st']
      // ...
   }
}
```

It is just a structure, you would have to finish it.

The code is looping through every record of your input table, let's call it `$inputRows`. It is important if the `user_id` changes, because this will start a new output row. As long as `user_id` remains the same, the code just adds further address types to the current output row. So, several input rows are grouped to one output row. All the output rows are then collected in an `$outputArray`.

Please note:

1) the dump you show in your question shows an array containing objects. In my answer, I create an array containing arrays as output. Usually, I prefer working merely with associative arrays as they offer more freedom in choosing names. If you want to work with objects, just alter the code accordingly. (`$outputObject->name = ...` instead of `$outputObject['name']` = ...)

2) I *assume* that the user_id criteria is relevant for grouping input rows to new output rows. I hope this is correct ;-D

**EDIT:** If there are several records for address type, one could add an additional array layer like this:

```
   ...
   ...
   // Create a suitable address subarray and fill it.
   if ($row->address_type == 'BT') {
       // If the array that collects several bts has not been created, create it.
       if (!isset($outputRow['bt']) {
           $outputRow['bt'] = array();
       }

       // Create an array with the bt address data
       $addressData = array();
       $addressData['firstname'] = $row->firstname;
       $addressData['lastname'] = $row->lastname;
       ...

       // Add the bt address data to the collection of bts. 
       $outputRow['bt'][] = $addressData;
   } 
   if ($row->address_type == 'ST') {
      // dito, but for ['st']
      // ...
   }
```

With slightly more requirements, I recommend outsourcing the part that collects address data to an own function so the whole code remains readable.

Comment: Thank you, that is my start point, is working, but, if user have more than 1 ST or BT it doesn't show it, only overwrite what is there, so I added a "counter" for each one, $cst = 0 and $cbt = 0, and inside each IF type = 'BT' or ST I added the "sum" $cst++; ... following the logic in your code if user id is the same it will add another key [0], [1]... and so on until user id is different, the "counters" gets reset to 0, but is not working, on the first loop it shows [bt]=>array ([7]...) then for the next user it works fine... kind of weird...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... I am not sure if you need a counter (or if I understand the requirement right). Please see my suggestion in the code.